# Failed to build gem native extension nio4r in Vagrant SSH windows 7 32-bit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, vagrant, vagrant-windows

I'm setting up Rails environment using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) with the box [ubuntu/trusty32](https://app.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/boxes/trusty32) in Windows 7 32-bit host. I'm stuck with `bundle install --path=./vendor/bundle`. I got the following error:

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /vagrant/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nio4r-2.1.0/ext/nio4r
/home/vagrant/.rbenv/versions/2.4.1/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170911-24730-8nkvsn.rb extconf.rb
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking for sys/select.h... yes
checking for poll.h... yes
checking for sys/epoll.h... yes
checking for sys/event.h... no
checking for port.h... no
checking for sys/resource.h... yes
creating Makefile

Text file busy @ unlink_internal - ./siteconf20170911-24730-8nkvsn.rb

Gem files will remain installed in /vagrant/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/gems/nio4r-2.1.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /vagrant/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.4.0/extensions/x86-linux/2.4.0-static/nio4r-2.1.0/gem_make.out

An error occurred while installing nio4r (2.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install nio4r -v '2.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.

In Gemfile:
  rails_admin was resolved to 1.2.0, which depends on
    rails was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
      actioncable was resolved to 5.0.6, which depends on
        nio4r
```

The problem seems to be the issue of the gem `nio4r`. I have tried these:

- `gem install bundler`
- `bundle update`
- `gem uninstall nio4r`
- `gem install nio4r` (this successfully installed the gem)
- `rm Gemfile.lock`
- `bundle install`

None of the above works. I also tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.2-dev
```

But it couldn't find the package.

```
E: Unable to locate package ruby2.2-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby2.2-dev'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error mainly addresses to the message `Text file busy @ unlink_internal - ./siteconf20170911-24730-8nkvsn.rb`. [I found a solution and I followed the steps described in the article](http://joequery.me/guides/bundle-install-text-file-busy/).

By changing bundle path to a directory that's local to the VM (not on a shared folder) made the error gone away.

1. Create a new directory

   ```
   mkdir ~/.bundles
   ```
2. Add this to `/vagrant/.bundle/config`

   ```
   BUNDLE_PATH: "/home/vagrant/.bundles/PROJECT_NAME_HERE"
   BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS: "1"
   ```
3. Run `bundle install`